# ImportError: cannot import name Zencoder

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm trying to excute my script which is require zencoder module , i'm pretty sure its installed but i keep getting the following msg

```
python zencoder.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zencoder.py", line 14, in <module>
    from zencoder import Zencoder
  File "/opt/zencoder/zencoder.py", line 14, in <module>
    from zencoder import Zencoder
ImportError: cannot import name Zencoder
```

zencode module already installed via pip and located here

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

i added the following to my bash_profile and still issue persistent

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

here is the location of the packages

```
Requirement already up-to-date: zencoder in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    Requirement already up-to-date: requests>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from zencoder)
```

any advise or tips why i'm still having this issue

Comment: Can you see the zencoder packade when you do a `pip freeze`?

Comment: your local script name might shadow the actual zencoder module. Rename your script.

Comment: Note that when module you're trying to import is not installed you should get an error: `ImportError: no module named '...'` So the problem is not with installation but with something else, try renaming your script like @languitar said

Comment: already renamed the script and that does not work for me

Comment: pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.3
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.2.0
requests==2.13.0
six==1.10.0
zencoder==0.6.5

Comment: Could you show us the rest of your script? Or at least the lines leading up to line 14, where you do the import?

Comment: sure , from zencoder import Zencoder
from ftplib import FTP

Comment: Perhaps add the 14 lines to the question? :)

Comment: @SimonFraser its the import section :   from  zencoder import Zencoder

Comment: Right, but you might be reusing the name zencoder, or doing something else in those lines, and we don't know what they are.

Comment: not at all simon , 14 lines only contain this ( from zencoder import Zencoder from ftplib import FTP ) nothing more nothing less

Answer (score 0):

1st check Zencoder is available in your python library ,

```
pip freeze | grep "Zencoder"
```

you are trying to import Zencoder from your zencoder.py file

that doesn't have Zencoder 
replace

```
from zencoder import Zencoder
```

with

```
import Zencoder
```

or
replace your script file with non-defined name that would avoid conflict with the defined name and then try.

```
from zencoder import Zencoder
```

Comment: @Rahual , I try all of this before i post it here , the same result

Comment: On terminal open ipython  and  write " from zencoder import Zencoder " check is it showing error !! or not